# accessing values of variables in broadcast receiver which are defined in main activity(on incoming call)

Tags: android

I am trying to make an android app which will send sms(content of sms is will be specified by user)to incoming call. I am using broadcast receiver in which i want to use value of edit text(content of sms) from main activity(when an incoming call arrives). I tried with Intent but i am not getting solution. please help.

main activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

   et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
   btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); 
}
 public void clicksave(View shilpa)
 {
s1=et1.getText().toString();
}
```

Broadcast receiver:

```
public class MyCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
static String incomingNumber="";
Context ct;

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
    {
        incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

                        try 
                        {
                            SmsManager smsmanager=SmsManager.getDefault();  
                            smsmanager.sendTextMessage(incomingNumber, null,"######",null,null);
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Message sent succesfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "SMS failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
      }

  } 
}
```

Comment: can you post some code so we can see what you've tried?

Comment: please post your code

Comment: be clear with your codes..

Comment: Well, your activity could not exists when the user receive the call, how you are going to handle that? Save the message in the preferences and read it when the call comes

Comment: can you please post syntax for that?

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think that the Activity will be alive when the user receive the call?

The best way is to save the value inside the Preferences of the application and read the value when the call comes

```
final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
final String message = preferences.getString("message");
```

then use the `message` variable.

```
smsmanager.sendTextMessage(incomingNumber, null, message, null,null);
```

In your main activity, save the value wrote in the EditText in the preferences using

```
final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit();
editor.putString("message", message);
editor.commit();
```

And you should be OK. If you search online, there are ways to comunicate with the Activity by saving the reference to it, but I don't think it would help in your code (and I don't like the approach, anyway)

Comment: when i am writing this code on button click , giving force close on button click event

Comment: final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit();
editor.putString("message", message);
editor.commit();

Answer (score 0):

finally i got solution for this

in main activity:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
Editor editor = pref.edit();
 editor.putString("message", message);
editor.commit();
```

in broadcast receiver:

```
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
    String a=pref.getString("message", null);
```